# LINQ query with multiple joins throwing null reference error

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a LINQ query with 3 joins and a grouping operation that is throwing a null reference error. In the below query (I'm sorry for the length) if you skip to the 'eDTK_PDP_Description'  field, it's that one that it causing the problem. I realize that I have the DefaultIfEmpty specification for the last join but I thought if I assign a value to the field from that join if it's null that should solve the problem. What am I doing wrong here? Thanks!

```
Dim UpdateSiebelPDP1 = From j In ( _
                           From PDP In SiebelMultPDPDescNoNull _
                           Group Join Siebel In ProdBase _
                                On PDP.Siebel_PDP_Code Equals Siebel.Siebel_PDP_Code _
                           Into g = Group _
                           From Result In g _
                           Group Join EDTK In eDTKBase _
                                On PDP.Siebel_PDP_Code Equals EDTK.eDTK_PDP_Code _
                           Into h = Group _
                           From Result2 In h _
                           Group Join EDTK2 In EDTKPDPOneDescDet _
                                On PDP.Siebel_PDP_Code Equals EDTK2.PDP_Description _
                           Into i = Group _
                           From Result3 In i.DefaultIfEmpty _
                           Select Result.Siebel_PLI, _
                                  Result.Siebel_PDP_Code, _
                                  Update_DAD_Flag = If(Result.Siebel_DAD_Flag Is Nothing, "Yes", "No"), _
                                  System = "Siebel", _
                                  PDD_PDP_Description = If(Result2.PDD_PDP_Description Is Nothing, _
                                                           "", Result2.PDD_PDP_Description), _
                                  Siebel_PDP_Description = "Multiple", _
                                  eDTK_PDP_Description = If(Result3.PDP_Description Is Nothing, _
                                                            "Multiple", Result3.PDP_Description)) _
                            Group j By j.Siebel_PLI, _
                                       j.Siebel_PDP_Code, _
                                       j.Update_DAD_Flag, _
                                       j.System, _
                                       j.PDD_PDP_Description, _
                                       j.Siebel_PDP_Description, _
                                       j.eDTK_PDP_Description _
                            Into k = Group _
                            Select New With { _
                                    Siebel_PLI, _
                                    Siebel_PDP_Code, _
                                    Update_DAD_Flag, _
                                    System, _
                                    PDD_PDP_Description, _
                                    Siebel_PDP_Description, _
                                    eDTK_PDP_Description}
```

Comment: Off topic, but... *Barf* VB even makes something as sexy LINQ look bad.

Comment: Obviously one of your objects is null.  I would treat your query like a SQL statement and start removing pieces until you identify the join that is causing the issue and then digging in from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `Result3` is null and you're trying to access a property on it. That's why your `if` isn't actually solving the problem. You can't check if `Result3.SomeField` is null if `Result3` is null because the attempted access causes a `NullRefereceException` so basically, you need to check if `Result3` is null before you go about trying to use it for assignment. If it is, then you should use some default value. I'll give a general idea, although it's not going to be VB cause I don't write that nonsense :P

```
   if (Result3 != null)
        eDTK_PDP_Description = Result3.SomeField;
   else
        eDTK_PDP_Description = defaultValue;
```

You'll have to decide for yourself how to you want to put this check into your query. The whole thing is a bit much for me and I don't know what you would want to assign there in the case that `Result3` is null.